# Unable to retrieve json object content in javascript

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I am unable to see the java created json in javascript. Any help?

**Java**

```
JSONObject psngrDetailJsonMap = new JSONObject();
                            if (firstNameList.size() > 0) {
                                for (int n = 0; n < firstNameList.size(); n++) {
                                    try {
                                        psngrDetailJsonMap.put(String.valueOf(n), lastNameList.get(n) + ","
                                                + firstNameList.get(n) + ","
                                                + firstEmailOfEachPsngr.get(n));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
modelAndView.addObject("psngrDetailsMap",
                                    psngrDetailJsonMap);
    System.out.println("PAXES DETAIL MAP"+psngrDetailJsonMap.toString());
```

System out -> *PAXES DETAIL MAP{"0":"SMITH,JOHN MR,J.SMITH@BUSINESS.COM","1":"SMITH,BARBARA MRS,B.SMITH@GMAIL.COM"}*

**JSP**

```
<input type="hidden" id="psngrDetailsMap" value="${psngrDetailsMap}" name="psngrDetailsMap"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
var jso = $("#psngrDetailsMap").val();
    alert(jso);
```

alert o/p is ->   **{**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Friso Don't know why scriptlets mentioned by you are causing compilation error and I could not build.

This JSTL code instead, worked for me:

```
<core:set var="psngrdetail" scope="session" value="${psngrDetailsMap}" />
<input type="hidden" id="psngrDetailsMap" name="psngrDetailsMap" value='<core:out value="${psngrdetail}"/>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
value=<%= psngrDetailsMap %>
```

in your JSP

You could also do:

```
var jso=<%= psngrDetailsMap %>
```